# Escaping spaces in tab-completion in a Cygwin shell subprocess on GNU Emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, cygwin, tab-completion

I use GNU Emacs on Windows and Cygwin as my shell.  If I create a Cygwin shell subprocess with M-x shell, I get a proper bash prompt.  If I type this:

```
cd ~/My<tab>
```

it tab-completes to

```
cd ~/My Documents/
```

which is correct in Emacs/Tramp, but useless in the Cygwin bash shell subprocess, since the space has to be escaped with a backslash.

How do I get this tab-completion to automatically insert a backslash?

Comment: Do you have something weird in your `/etc/bash_completion.d/`? Also does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852389/bash-autocomplete-doesnt-escape-space-and-doesnt-mark-directories-in-ubuntu-11) solves your problem?